# Conditional matching PCRE regex: how do a lookbehind with various size?

Tags: regex, pcre

I try to match a simple pattern P1 (whitespaces or tabs, then ## then text):

```
[ \t]*##\S*
```

But sometimes, I want to match with another pattern P2 (neither whitespaces nor tabs, then ## then text):

```
[^ \t]*##\S*
```

P2 must be used when ##\S* follow \S*

P1 must be used otherwise

Examples of expected match results:

```
##foo
must give
##foo

      ##foo (6 whitespaces before pattern)
must give
      ##foo (because there is some whitespaces before the pattern ##foo and not any non-whitespace characters)

foo   ##bar
must give
##bar (because there is some non-whitespace charecters before the pattern ##foobar)

foo bar   ##foobar
must give
##foobar
```

I tried lookbehind method but it's not possible because there is no fixed size.

It would be very nice if someone could help me...

Comment: Do you want to capture all the `'must give'` strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the effect of what you're after using capture groups:

```
^(\s*##\S*)|^\S+\s*(##\S*)
```

Then something like

```
     ## foo
```

will be matched by the first alternative, and the result can be obtained from the first capture group, whereas

```
foo  ## bar
```

will be matched by the second alternative, and the "## bar" can be obtained from the second capture group.

Comment: Great! Thank you Stuart! Final regex is: ^(\s*##\S*)|^\S+(?:\s|\S)*(##\S*)